# Prevent field editing using PHP session

Tags: php, authorization, access-control

Is it a good idea/good practice to use a PHP session variable to protect against users editing hidden/input field values? For instance, lets say I have the following fields:

```
<input type="hidden" object_id="1" />
<input type="text" object_id="2" />
etc...
```

I need to have the `object_id` on the front end so I can tell which database entries need to be manipulated when the user submits (providing they are authorized to act on the data). The `$_SESSION` variable would look something like `[obj_id = 1, obj_id = 2]`. Part of the authorization process makes sure that all of the entries the user is trying to act upon are present in the session. If there is some discrepancy (e.g. an element with `object_id="3"`) the user is not authorized.

Are there solutions that are more widely accepted or does something similar to this usually suffice?

Comment: If it is stored in session, why bother storing in hidden fields? If they are not allowed to modify the element in question, why bother storing in a form that might allow that change? I would say this is generally bad practice. You should probably rethink your application flow.

Comment: ^ I agree that stuff already in sessions does not belong in hidden fields. Why? If you rely on the GET or POST vars rather than the session for those, you are creating a security disaster.

Comment: One should ask themselves, Who owns this state? If you are having to jump through hoops in order to obtain the intended functionality, then you are likely attempting to store state where it does not belong. A user session should contain user session data. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: @steve Most of the fields are supposed to be edited by end users. I could probably do away with the hidden fields in retrospect. Do your arguments still apply to fields that the user is intended to edit? If so, I'll try to rethink how things work.

Comment: @mcon they sure do. If they are suppose to be edited by the end user then post is fine. Data validity should be determined by table constraints where possible. If you don't have to trust the user, for the love of God, don't! :)

Comment: Always always do serverside validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, you still need to trust the end user to provide you with the correct data to be modified. The only thing that you can verify in that context is that the values provided look like valid data to be inserted into the database, and this is usually the databases job itself, as what is valid data is the database table's state to determine.

There are many ways to approach this. Unless I knew more about what you are trying to do, I cannot provide a sound detailed solution.

Good luck

Comment: I'll comment here to contain our conversation because I have one more thing to ask. What about a case where all of the data the user input is valid, but the user edited `object_id` so they touch a database entry that they are authorized to modify, but shouldn't be modifying in this context?

Comment: @mcon that requires a very in depth discussion about software design itself. I would be happy to have it, but comments are not the place :)

Comment: Agreed; comments are not the place for such a discussion. I decided to make my authorization process much more thorough so I can avoid the session all together. I'll accept your answer for the suggestions and advice. Thanks!

Comment: @mcon that sounds wise. If you get me in a chat session I'll show you a lot of neat tricks I use in php to maintain state while still reducing code complexity. Php is more powerful than people give it credit.